# fwrite() puts unknown zero

Tags: c, file, fwrite

I have one strange problem while using fwrite() in C.After editing of file with integers, i get zero ("0") before my last element which added by fwrite().My exercise is to divide integers in file on groups which are consisted of 10 elements or less.

For example, i have : 
 `{2, 3, 9, 4, 6, 7, 5, 87, 65,12, 45, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}`

after editing i need : 
`{2, 3, 9, 4, 6, 7, 5, 87, 65, 12, 87, 45, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 45 };`

With code below I get: 
`{2, 3, 9, 4, 6, 7, 5, 87, 65, 12, 87, 45, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 45 };` 
In the process of step-by-step debugging *fwrite() works only two times*, it wites 87 after first ten elements, and 45 after remained.Zero wasn`t writed by fwrite().Is that so?From where it comes finally?

My code:

```
while (!feof(fp)) {

        fread(&elems[k], sizeof(int), 1, fp);
        fwrite(&elems[k], sizeof(int), 1, hp);
        ++k;

        if (k == 10 || feof(fp)){
            for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
                if (elems[i] > max_number){
                    max_number = elems[i];
                }
            }
            fwrite(&max_number, sizeof(int), 1, hp);
            for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
                elems[i] = 0;
            }
            max_number = INT_MIN;
            k = 0;
        }

    }
```

Thank for answers!

Comment: It is almost always wrong to use `feof`. I will try to find one of the duplicates to mark this with in a few minutes.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["while( !feof( file ) )" is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)

Comment: @user3386109: But he doesn't seem to be reading and writing to the same stream. fp vs hp file handles.

Comment: @ZanLynx Yup, just noticed that. I've retracted my comments.

Answer (score 1):

- Using `feof` will result in reading an extra item.
- Must check for errors from `fwrite` and `fread` calls.

  - One possible error is the `EOF` error.
  - If `fread` returns 0 items read the value will be left at whatever it was before. Probably 0. Which is probably where your extra 0 comes from.

Comment: Ok, i get it.And how do i delete that extra "0"?Could i check it after last fread and cut instantly if it appears?But what if in my file, one of integers is zero itself?This simple task seems too problematic in c.